# Willingness to pay, WTP, for decision tree

Tags: regression, logistic, modeling

So I have this ice cream `x1` and this ice cream `x2`, I asked a bunch of people if they would buy ice cream `x2` for this price `p1` when the price of ice cream `x1` is this other price `A`. If they wouldn't buy `x2` for `p1` they move to the right and get offered a lower price `p3`, but still, the price of `x1` is held constant at `A`, if they would buy this time the go to the left and get a price `p6` for `x2` where `p3 < p6 < p1` this continue until they reach one end nod of the tree.

[image]

So I have this buy-or-not data for a lot of people.

At first glance I thought I could derive a simple logistic regression to get the willingness to pay, WTP, but this would not be the accurate way to do the analysis because the people would be split into two groups, left of `p1` and right of `p1` i.e those who would buy `x2` for `p1` and those who wouldn't buy `x2` for `p1` and those to the left will never be offered `p3, p6, p7, p12, p13, p14, p15.`

So, what would be the right way to derive some kind of WTP of a decision tree like this? Can the data somehow be normalized so that a logistic regression can be used?

Comment: If my reading is correct, this doesn't sound like a standard decision tree, nor does it sound like the kind of problem decision trees are typically used for.

Otherwise, as for determining maximum WTP, I don't see the problem. People who buy at p1 are willing to pay p1, and would presumably be willing to pay every price lower than p1 as well.

Comment: Yes, and they will in next step get a higher price ```p2```, aint sure they will pay ```p2```but if they do they get the higher price ```p4``` etc

Comment: So your study design tries to get the maximum WTP for each participant, is that right? You mentioned regression, what independent variables are you using and what dependent variable are you trying to associate with them?

Comment: Yes, well, at first glance i thought of a logistic regression setting the dependent variable to the binary 0/1-value for buy or not buy at given price and the price as independent value.

Comment: If you have a specific question you are trying to answer with your model, knowing that would help. If you are looking for something valid to do with the data you've got, there are a lot of things you could do.

From what you are describing you have a data set that contains your sample's maximum willingness to pay for x2 given a fixed price for x1. That strikes me as useful for answering the question of what price will maximize revenue (or sales, or whatever) for x2 given the price of x1 moreso than whether or not "a sale" will result from those prices. Unless you have some other predictors.

Comment: Well, yes, I have already calculated the WTP as a score variable which is pretty easy. But "can I somehow normalize the data so that a logistic regression can be used?". The logistic regression would say something like "given a price of p this x% will buy the ice cream".

Comment: As far as I can see, there is nothing to regress on and no logistic regression to do. You can get the proportion willing to pay a price directly from your tree.